# Target element that has an element with certain a CSS property using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to target the element with class "keyimage" that have an `a` with a certain background image.

That's my code:

```
$( ".keyimage" ).has( "a[style^="background-image: url('https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/white.jpg')"]" ).css( "display", "none" );
```

Any idea why it isn't working?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Please supply the relevant HTML so we can test it out.

Comment: I think the issue is with the ".

Comment: any idea how to write " without ruining the code

Comment: I think I see what you mean.  You can use single quotes instead or even skip quotes, provided your version of JQuery accepts that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$( ".keyimage" ).has( "a[style^=\"background-image: url('https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/white.jpg')\"]" ).css( "display", "none" );
--------------------------------^----------------------------------------------------------------------------------^
```

You need to add `\` in your string to skip quotes

Or you can enclosed with the back-tick instead

```
$( ".keyimage" ).has( `a[style^="background-image: url('https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/white.jpg')"]` ).css( "display", "none" );
```

Comment: Now I'm not getting errors anymore but it's not working. Any idea how I can achieve the described above?

Comment: Post your relevant html too else we can't help you